# IGFaces gives weird result

Tags: graphs-and-networks, igraphm

I'm using the IGraph/M package to perform some calculations on graphs. Specifically, I want to use `IGFaces` to determine how many edges/vertices each face has for some calculations later down the line. What's going wrong is that the faces that it produces are not the ones I expect.I am able to reproduce this here:

```
g = Graph[
  Range[5],
  {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{1.993577`, 27.381231`}, {2.920982`, 
     27.005762`}, {2.048629`, 26.343576`}, {2.96684`, 
     25.922899`}, {2.108422`, 25.318638`}}, 
VertexLabels -> "Name"]
IGFaces[g]
```

Output:

[image]

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 5, 3}, {3, 5, 4}}
```

I do not expect these faces at all, I was expecting (and hoping) that I would get all the triangles you see there and big face that covers the "outer" edge, something like

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 3}}
```

I thought that by providing coordinates explicitly I would not have issues since it fixes the embedding. Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Note that this graph is actually part of a bigger graph and the code is part of a bigger much messier code so it might be hard to provide additional details.

I'm using "IGraph/M 0.5.1 (October 12, 2020)" and Mathematica 12.3

Comment: [`PlanarFaceList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanarFaceList.html) is another alternative. Though for large graphs, `IGFaces` is much faster.

Comment: @GregHurst `PlanarFaceList` is part of Mathematica 13.0 (which I don't have) which is one of the main reasons I was using IGraph in the first place, but nonetheless a nice alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the answer quite quickly after posting this. The function I needed was `IGCoordinatesToEmbedding[]`. This function gives an embedding which can be passed on to `IGFaces[]` and also `IGDual[]` (which I also need). Result:

```
IGFaces[IGCoordinatesToEmbedding[g]]
```

Output:

```
{{1, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 5, 4}}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. You can plot the graph using `IGLayoutPlanar` (which uses `IGPlanarEmbedding` and `IGEmbeddingToCoordinates`) to see where the faces that `IGFaces` gives by default come from.